# Variable with underscore definition inside class

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

```
class Ticket:
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price
    @property
    def price(self):
        return self._price
    @price.setter
    def price(self, new_price):
        if new_price < 0:
            raise ValueError('Try again')
        self._price = new_price
```

In the above class definition, `self._price` is used in both functions of `price`, but the variable `_price` is not defined before it is used.

This class works good like

```
t = Ticket(4)
print(t.price)
t.price = 34
```

I was wondering how this class works? Where is the variable `_price` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that `_price` is never defined. But there's no error because this code never tries to access it. The problem is here:

```
def __init__(self, price):
    self.price = price
```

This code ends up replacing your getter with the value 4 (or whatever you pass in). We can demonstrate this by adding prints to your getters and setters.

```
class Ticket:
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price
    @property
    def price(self):
        print('get price')
        return self._price
    @price.setter
    def price(self, new_price):
        print('set price')
        if new_price < 0:
            raise ValueError('Try again')
        self._price = new_price
```

You will see that nothing is printed.. Change to this...

```
def __init__(self, price):
    self._price = price
```

And your getters and setters are now getting called

Comment: Is this because Python first runs through the `def`s, setting `price()` as a property, and then calls `__init__()`, which overrides the property?

Comment: @MichaelKolber I assume so

Comment: I just checked, that is why. Adding `print()` statements in the main class definition before `@property`, before `@price.setter`, and in `__init__()` before `self.price = price` will show that that's the order that the interpreter looks at it. Commenting out `self.price = price` raises an exception, as expected.